# Does "handicapped" mean mentally ill or physically disabled?

Tags: word-usage

Does the word "handicapped" mean mentally ill or physically disabled?

Comment: Hi Anixx, when asking questions like this it is often helpful to consult a dictionary first. If you have already done so and are still confused, please post what you found in the dictionary in your question. (If you edit to add this information, as well as what you're still confused about and flag the question for reopening, I'd be happy to do so :))

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

"Handicapped" can refer to either a mental or a physical disability. If it's not clear from the context, then spell it out. "Sally suffered from a severe mental handicap" or "... physical handicap".

"Handicapped" can refer to many other sorts of limitations on a person's or thing's abilities, like we talk about someone being "handicapped by his poor education" or "the web site is handicapped by a poor color scheme".

Comment: It's also a technical term in golf, where it refers to an artificial difficulty.

Comment: @TRiG That's true in other games as well (Go for example). :)